# Не получается изменить background image с помощью js

Tags: javascript

В css установлен фон для body

```
background: url(../img/apple.jpg) center no-repeat;
```

В той же папке с изображениями, что и данная картинка, лежит другая - apple_true
С помощью js могу менять только цвет фона элемента, но не могу менять картинку
То есть так работает:

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.background = 'blue';
```

а вот так уже не работает:

```
let body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.background = 'url(../img/apple_true.jpg) center no-repeat);';
```

в чем загвоздка? туплю уже почти час((

хотелось бы решить проблему именно с помощью чистого js, без jQuery

Заранее спасибо

Comment: у вас скобка и точка с запятой лишняя после no-repeat `no-repeat);';`

Comment: спасибо, заработало)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Картинка фона, прописанная в файле css, ищется по пути относительно этого css файла. Картинка фона, прописанная в скрипте, ищется относительно url страницы.

Comment: спасибо, но у меня все равно не получается, видимо, верно написать адрес этой долбанной картинки:( если в проекте есть index.html, а этом же уровне папка img, а в ней картинка apple_true, то для того, чтобы обратиться к этой картинке из файла js, мне нужно писать путь относительно index.html? то есть что-то типа url(img/apple_true.jpg)? просто проблема в том, что так тоже не получается почему-то

Comment: @hamster789 `url(./img/apple_true.jpg)`

Comment: спасибо, теперь получилось)