# Как изменить фоновое изображение средствами javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Фоновое изображение прописано в стилях

```
body {
    height: 670px;
    background: url(../img/apple.jpg) center no-repeat;
}
```

Надо изменить средствами javascript. Делаю так, но не работает:

```
Let body = document.querySelector('body'); 

     body.background = '../img/apple_true.jpg';
```

Делал как здесь:  [Не получается изменить background image с помощью js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/966777/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-background-image-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-js) , но все равно не получается.
Что я делаю не так?

```
body.background = "url('../img/apple_true.jpg')";
```

Переписал так, но все равно не работает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может, неправильно задаю ссылку на изображение?
Скрипт находится в папке js, а изображение в папке img!

```
body.style.background = "url('img/apple_true.jpg')";



document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(img/apple_true.jpg)";
```

Работает и так и так! Спасибо всем участникам за помощь!

Подскажите, пожалуйста: почему ответ Stranger я вижу в одном формате, а Sergey в другом? Я недавно на площадке, и не очень хорошо ориентируюсь.

Comment: url(...) в css коде есть, а в js коде нет

Comment: `body.background = "url('../img/apple_true.jpg')";` исправил, но ничего

Comment: body.style.background = ...

Comment: Теперь заработало! Спасибо! Не вижу, как отметить лучший ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(../img/apple_true.jpg)";
```

Comment: Спасибо! Уже заработало!